# Adding a row with transparent background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, transparency, nstableview

I have an NSTableView, with an "add" button below it. When I click on the button, a new row gets added to the table and is ready for user input.

The row appears in a white color. Can I set the color of the row to a transparent color? Is this possible? I cannot figure out how to do this.

My code for setting my table to be transparent:

```
[myTable setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[[myTable enclosingScrollView] setDrawsBackground: NO];
```

Code for adding a row:

```
[myTableArray addObject:@""];
[myTable reloadData];
[myTable editColumn:0 row:[myTableArray count]-1 withEvent:nil select:YES];
```

Comment: can anybody provide some help, is this possible

Answer (score 1):

try setting the cell's background color transparent

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

it works for me

Comment: this works for touch app but i need for non touch cocoa app :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to do some subclassing to accomplish what you're trying to do.

By subclassing your NSTableView you can override the preparedCellAtColumn:row: method like so:

```
- (NSCell*) preparedCellAtColumn:(NSInteger)column row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTextFieldCell *edit_field;

    edit_field = (NSTextFieldCell*) [super preparedCellAtColumn:column row:row];
    if ( [self editedRow] == row && [self editedColumn] == column  ) {
        [edit_field setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
        [edit_field setDrawsBackground:NO];

    }

    return edit_field;
}
```

However, the NSTableView documentation indicates that your cell has another method called, which seems to reset the color. (editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event:)  Creating a subclass of NSTextViewCell that overrides this method may do what you're looking for.

**EDIT**
Searching through the documentation I found this:

> If the receiver isn’t a text-type NSCell object, no editing is performed. Otherwise, the field editor (textObj) is sized to aRect and its superview is set to controlView, so it exactly covers the receiver.

So what you need to customize in this case is the field editor, which is covering up any display changes you're performing on the NSTableView or the cell.

The field editor is returned by the window delegate's method windowWillReturnFieldEditor:toObject:

This should let you set the properties of the edited cell before returning it to the NSTableView

**EDIT**
Tried this to no avail but might help out:

```
-(id) windowWillReturnFieldEditor:(NSWindow *)sender toObject:(id)client{
    NSText *editor =  [window fieldEditor:YES forObject:client];
    [editor setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [editor setDrawsBackground:NO];
    return [editor autorelease];
}
```

Comment: thabks fr ur answer i will try this as soon as i get back on this project.